# Задать цвет заливки при действии

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, blend

В CastomControl нужно добавить ещё одну кисть, которая будет закрашивать фон кнопки при наведении. Задать задал, вроде и цвет правильно указывается, и привязка без ошибок компилятора, но во время работы при наведении на кнопку, она меняется на прозрачный(и соответственно начинается  кнопки эдакий приступ эпелепсии у фона). Как понял, где то не правильно что-то задал и поэтому во время выполнения не удается получить мою заданную кисть и соответсвенно ставится Null. Не могу понять где именно проблема.

```
public class APIButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectFillProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SelectFill), typeof(Brush), typeof(APIButton));
    [Category("Кисть")]
    public Brush SelectFill
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(SelectFillProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectFillProperty, value); }
    }

    static APIButton()
    {

        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(APIButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(APIButton)));
    }
}
```

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:APIButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:APIButton}">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="border" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="0" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" RadiusX="{Binding RadX, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:APIButton}}}" RadiusY="{Binding RadY, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:APIButton}}}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="border" Value="{Binding local:APIButton.SelectFill}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Надо было изменить этот параметр,

```
 Value="{Binding local:APIButton.SelectFill}"
```

следующим образом:

```
 Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}, Path=SelectFill}"
```

Comment: Возможно, вам нужно просто `Value="{TemplateBinding SelectFill}"`?

Comment: TemplateBinding в Setter выдает исключение компилятора.
Проблема по сути была в том, что нужно было явно указать, что параметр находятся в объекте родителе.